# C# WPF MaterialDesign ScrollViewer hide block at right bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, scrollviewer

I am using the MaterialDesign XAML templates as the basis for my self styled ScrollViewer. When the horizontal, as well as the vertical ScrollBars are visible, this square appears at the bottom right. How can I get rid of this, or hide it?

Here is my template:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomScrollViewer" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Border x:Name="perp_ScrollViewerBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_CT.ScrollViewer.Border}" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_CT.ScrollViewer.Background}" BorderThickness="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_DT.ScrollViewer.ContentBorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_DT.ScrollViewer.ContentBorderCornerRadius}">
            <ScrollViewer Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ScrollViewer.Content>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="5"></ContentPresenter>
                </ScrollViewer.Content>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollBar}">
                <Setter Property="wpf:ScrollBarAssist.ThumbCornerRadius" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_DT.ScrollViewer.ThumbCornerRadius}"/>
                <Setter Property="wpf:ScrollBarAssist.ButtonsVisibility" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_DT.ScrollViewer.ButtonsVisibility}"/>
                <Setter Property="wpf:ScrollBarAssist.ThumbWidth" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_DT.ScrollViewer.ThumbWidth}"/>
                <Setter Property="wpf:ScrollBarAssist.ThumbHeight" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=perp_DT.ScrollViewer.ThumbHeight}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="wpf:ScrollBarAssist.ButtonsVisibility" Value="Collapsed"></Condition>
                            <Condition Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"></Condition>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1 5 2 5"></Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="wpf:ScrollBarAssist.ButtonsVisibility" Value="Collapsed"></Condition>
                            <Condition Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"></Condition>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 2 5 3"></Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it, simply add this:

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Setter Property="wpf:ScrollViewerAssist.CornerRectangleVisibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
            </Style>
```